# The easiest way to achieve a responsive orientation enum? java

Tags: java, enums, direction

I will quickly display what I want to achieve in the "clearest" way:

```
public enum Orientation {
    NORTH, WEST, SOUTH, EAST }

public enum Turn {
    LEFT, RIGHT }
```

So what I want those two enums to do is secure and efficiently look up the changed orientation according to the move:

```
Orientation orient = Orientation.NORTH;
// orient points to NORTH now
orient = orient.turn(Turn.LEFT);
// orient points to WEST now
```

The first way I tried to achieve this was through creating a map:

```
 EnumMap<Orientation, EnumMap<Turn, Orientation>>
```

And map all the directions statically but that is a huge chunk of map.get.put.get.... and is probably a bit too overdosed, altough resulting in this desired effect:

```
directionMap.get(NORTH).get(LEFT)
// the value would then be WEST
```

The next way I went was through a Compass class that links all orientations into a circle.. Working like a  LinkedCircuitList   ...<->NORTH<->EAST<->SOUTH<->WEST<->NORTH<->... So Compass could have a static function that calls any Member of that linked list and step to the left or to the right, resulting in the correct change of direction. But the code did not really work out the way I wanted it.

So my question in the end, does anybody has experience on that kind of code, or has an idea how to achieve the desired result in a nice enumerish way?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. Are you asking us how to implement the turn() method in the Orientation enum?

Comment: Im asking for ideas on how to implement such method in a nice and non-redundant way ( You could aways write a switch case, but that would be bad in terms of redundancy, as e.g. WEST.turn(LEFT) would always result in the same direction, namely SOUTH)

Comment: @Jan Do you really need an enum for `Turn`? I mean that can only ever be `LEFT` or `RIGHT`/

Comment: @RohitJain Its always recommended to use an enum in such a situation I guess.
In the actual piece of code I am writing it is HARD_LEFT, LEFT, RIGHT, HARD_RIGHT for Turn  and   N, NE, E, SE, S, SW, W, NW for Orientation

Comment: I think associative array kind of fits here. You've to see how you properly implement it in this case. I think `Map` is the thing you need.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I see nothing wrong with the Map solution. If you want something more consise:

```
public enum Orientation {
    NORTH, EAST, SOUTH, WEST;

    private static Orientation[] vals = values();

    Orientation turnTo(Turn t) {
        return vals[(4 + this.ordinal() + (t == Turn.RIGHT ? 1 : -1)) % 4];
    }
}
```

This, however, is less clean and maintainable (it would break if someone changes the order of the enums).

A little cleaner (but less consise) :

```
public enum Orientation {
    NORTH(0), EAST(1), SOUTH(2), WEST(3);

    private final int p;

    Orientation(int p) {
        this.p = p;
    }

    private static Orientation[] vals = new Orientation[4];
    static {
        for( Orientation o : Orientation.values() )
            vals[o.p] = o;
    }

    Orientation turnTo(Turn t) {
        return vals[(4 + this.p + (t == Turn.RIGHT ? 1 : -1)) % 4];
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes unfortunately I read Josh Bloch telling me to not use ordinal indexing of exactly the same reason you're telling me.

Regarding that you consider the Map solution to be nice, as you can see in my comment above I have some more directions and turn possibilites, resulting in an even bigger code block for the static mapping (40 lines). Is that still assumed to be a good solution?

Comment: @Jan: I'd say that the Map solution is even better if the logic is more complicated. Perhaps you can simplify its construction logic (avoid too many if/else) by appending a numeric code both to the Orientation and the Turn (say to represent degrees).

Comment: I really did not think about using the modulo classes for getting the right indices and manage overflow.. thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Another way to trick java into accepting this is using methods instead of fields:

```
enum Orientation {

    NORTH {
        Orientation left(){return WEST;}
        Orientation right(){return EAST;}
    },
    EAST {
        Orientation left(){return NORTH;}
        Orientation right(){return SOUTH;}
    },
    SOUTH {
        Orientation left(){return EAST;}
        Orientation right(){return WEST;}
    },
    WEST {
        Orientation left(){return SOUTH;}
        Orientation right(){return NORTH;}
    };

    abstract Orientation left();
    abstract Orientation right();

    public Orientation turn(Turn where){
        return where == Turn.LEFT ? this.left() : this.right();
    }
}
```

You can save yourself the `turn()` and just write stuff like `Orientation.North.left()`, if you want to. Gives you very concise Syntax.

Answer (score 1):

I think your idea of a circular list is very good:

```
public enum Turn {
    LEFT(-1), RIGHT(1);

    private final int offset;

    private Turn(int offset) {
        this.offset = offset;
    }

    public int offset() {
        return this.offset;
    }
}

public enum Orientation {
    NORTH, EAST, SOUTH, WEST;

    private static final List<Orientation> orientations = 
        Arrays.asList(NORTH, EAST, SOUTH, WEST); // to not depend on ordinal

    public Orientation turn(Turn to) {
        int size = orientations.size();
        int myIndex = orientations.indexOf(this);
        int remainder = (myIndex + to.offset()) % size;
        int index = remainder < 0 ? size + remainder : remainder;
        return orientations.get(index);
    }
}
```

This seems quite extensible, i.e. HARD_LEFT would have a `-2` offset and the circular list of orientations should be ordered from left to right.

Comment: This is actually a nice approach :)

Comment: This causes an Array index out of bounds exception! An array in java does not hande the -1 index as the end of the array like in C. This answer should be corrected.

Comment: @Jan When does that exception occur?

Comment: Exception says: ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException:-1, Example code for exception:
Orientation orient = Orientation.NORTH;
orient.turn(Turn.LEFT);

Comment: @Jan I was just noticing that. I'll add a version for every version of Java.

Comment: @Jan Done with no dependency on Java 8. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

Does not use ordinals, and easy to understand:

```
public enum Orientation { NORTH, WEST, EAST, SOUTH;

    static {
        NORTH.left = WEST;
        NORTH.right = EAST;
        WEST.left = SOUTH;
        WEST.right = NORTH;
        EAST.left = NORTH;
        EAST.right = SOUTH;
        SOUTH.left = EAST;
        SOUTH.right = WEST;
    }

    private Orientation left;
    private Orientation right;

    public Orientation turnTo(Turn t) { return t == Turn.LEFT ? left : right; }
}
```